# Proving that a function with multiple parameters is onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Here's my situation:
I understand that to prove the "onto" ness of a function it is necessary to show that X can be expressed in terms of Y by isolating it using standard mathematics.

However, I am confused as to how one can prove the trait of being onto in a function that has multiple parameters and a infinite domain. My problem that I can't seem to make inroads on is as such:

Let F be a function: F: QxQ --> R by the rule F(p, q) = p + sqrt(3)*q for all (p, q) in QxQ.

How does one go about proving such a function is onto? I don't really know the way to do this for multiple parameters and my textbook nor notes are of much help.

Thank you for any assistance!

Edit: Onto-ness is not required, but I need to be able to prove one or the other.

Comment: I don't think $F$ is onto: $F(p,q)\not=sqrt2$ for all rationals $p$ and $q$.

Comment: How can your $F$ be onto? The domain is a countable set, so the image must also be at most countable--but $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, so it isn't possible that $F(\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q) = \mathbb R$

Comment: Perhaps the notation isn't making sense? My domain can't be countable, as Q is an infintite set and therefore its cartesian product should be as well. Basically, it's saying that if you give it a value of an ordered pair (P,Q) from the cartesian product of QxQ, this function results in a real. Which, is true, since Q and I are both in reals.

If you consider the function purely as P + sqrt(3)*Q with this understanding, that's what I'm curious about. I hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: Yes, but onto means that every *real* should be equal to $p+\sqrt3\cdot q$, for some *rational numbers* $p$ and $q$. I suspect a typo on your book/teacher's part.

Comment: I keep forgetting to mention this, and I apologize (I corrected my post): Onto-ness isn't required of the function, but they want proof one way or another.

Nvmd, I think I see what you're getting at. I hate not understanding any of this :\